# Error with APE Server Installation

Tags: uninstall, folder, installation, init.d, purge

I was trying to install APE-Server from the .deb file at the ape-server homepage (www.ape-project.org) and I ran into an error so wanted to try removing the installation and reinstalling.  I did a     sudo apt-get remove ape-server    which ran successfully but left ape-server folders in my /etc/ and /etc/init.d locations.  Me being an idiot new comer to linux decided that manually delete those folders.  Now when I reinstall the ape-server those folders don't get recreated and therefore I cannot send the

```
 /etc/init.d/ape-server [option]
```

command because the folder is not found.

When I try to sudo apt-get purge (or remove) ape-server I get the following

```
   sudo apt-get purge ape-server
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   The following packages will be REMOVED:
      ape-server*
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 92 not upgraded.
   1 not fully installed or removed.
   After this operation, 1,753kB disk space will be freed.
   Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
   (Reading database ... 43924 files and directories currently installed.) 
   Removing ape-server ...
   invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/ape-server not found.
   dpkg: error processing ape-server (--purge): 
   subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 100
   update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/ape-server: file does not exist
   dpkg: error while cleaning up:
   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
   Errors were encountered while processing:
     ape-server 
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My question is; how do I remove all of the ape-server installation packages that were installed so I can reinstall from scratch?

Comment: have you tried to trick dpkg by creating an empty file?

Comment: @Roland, I created an empty directory in `/etc/init.d/` called "ape-server" but I'm not sure what type of file its looking for within that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since we know it worked, I'll answer your question:*

Create an empty file:

- `/etc/init.d/ape-server`

Now remove the package, and it will be all clear.